# How to write a constructor that prevents creation of objects on certain conditions

Tags: java, object, constructor

I am trying to create a constructor for an object that inherits another object, but this constructor should also prevent the creation of the object on certain conditions.

I have this code:

```
class Foo
{
    double x;
    public Foo(double init_x)
    {
        x = init_x;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public Bar(double init_x)
    {
        if(init_x < 10)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        super(init_x);
    }
}
```

Here are the errors when the code is compiled with a main defined:

```
test2.java:13: error: constructor Foo in class Foo cannot be applied to given types;
        {
        ^
  required: double
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
test2.java:18: error: call to super must be first statement in constructor
            super(init_x);
                 ^
2 errors
```

My question is: why did I get the first error even though I clearly specified `Bar(double init_x)` and also for the second part if the super call has to be the first statement then how do I address this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You move the check until after the call to `super`. It's still before the method completes, so the caller will not see the object constructed - it prevents the construction at least in the view of the caller:

   ```
   class Bar extends Foo {
       public Bar(double init_x) throws Exception {
           super(init_x);
           if (init_x < 10) {
               throw new Exception();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. You do the check in another method that returns the value if it is correct, but throws an exception if it is not correct:

   ```
   class Bar extends Foo {
       private static double checkInitX(double init_x) throws Exception {
           if (init_x < 10) {
               throw new Exception();
           }
           return init_x;
       }

       public Bar(double init_x) throws Exception {
           super(checkInitX(init_x));
       }
   }
   ```

   You are allowed to call as an expression within the call to super any method that's not an instance method on the object that you're constructing. A good place to put that method is as a static method in the class.

But usually, option 1 is the best. Unless there is a very good reason not to call the super with an out-of-range value (like, the super constructor is very slow, or it throws another, confusing, exception if the value is out of range), option 2 is not necessary. (In the two cases mentioned, you're better off refactoring the superclass constructor)

Comment: I have one question now tht I think about it. why is it necessary to put the static keyword in the check function? I tried removing it and it gives an error.

Comment: @YandereLolicon165 A non-static method would be able to access instance variables (fields) or methods of the object, but you're not allowed to do that until you have invoked the superclass constructor. static methods can't do that, so they are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is stated in the error message you get: `error: call to super must be first statement in constructor`

Comment: But then if that is the case then the object has been created isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that throw exception in constructor is not good practice.
Of cause, this is just my opinion, but I think, it will be better to make simple factory method:

```
class Bar extends Foo
{
    //hide constructor
    private Bar(init_x){
        super(init_x);
    }

    //factory method
    public static Bar createBar(double init_x)
    {
        if(init_x >= 10)
        {
            return new Bar(init_x);
        }else{
            //you can return null, instead of throwing exception
            throw new Exception();            
        }
    }
}
```

And when you need instance of bar:

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    Bar bar = Bar.createBar(104.3);
    ...
}
```

Comment: @YandereLolicon165, you're right. thanx. just copypast mistake.